# Request metadata gets appended to the content of file while uploading to OneDrive using rest api

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When trying to upload files to one drive, request metadata gets appended to the file. Uploading procedure followed as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online. Upload session is created using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/test.txt:/createUploadSession with headers 
Authorization: bearer token, Content-Type:application/json and body 
{
  "item": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "name": "test.txt"
  }
}
```

using POST request via Postman. A success response with upload url is obtained, the data is uploaded through form-data body and the url is called(PUT request). success(201 created) response is obtained with file details. 
On opening the uploaded file in one drive we can see that request metadata is appended to the file( as shown below)

```
   ----------------------------898660285489541847705085

   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
   Content-Type: text/plain

   test

  ----------------------------898660285489541847705085--
```

test is the actual content in that "test.txt" file before uploading.Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you uploading the file with postman as well?

Comment: yes using postman

Comment: What about the value for the content-length and content-range fields?

Comment: I was able to upload without any issue by trying the same using python

Comment: Great to hear !